# Is it possible to use css wildcard class selector where there are multiple class values?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector where i can select all anchors with a class containing icon-*

```
<a class="icon-a icon-large scrollTo" href="#a"></a>
<a class="icon-large icon-b scrollTo" href="#b"></a>
<a class="icon-large scrollTo icon-c" href="#c"></a>
```

*I just jumbled up the icon- since i want to check if the css selector can handle all cases.*

I want to be able to change the style of all anchors that contains the class icon-*.  This code doesn't seem to work.

```
a [class^="icon-"], a [class*=" icon-"] {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1BA1E2;
}
```

Is Javascript my only option?

Comment: `color: #PINK;` the `#` is too much?

Comment: You can't have a class that contains space, so the second selector doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Barmar: But you can have a class *attribute* with a value that contains a space. It's right there in the markup - spaces are used to separate class names.

Comment: D'oh, right, the attribute selector doesn't parse it like a class selector does.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You were using an incorrect selector - `a [class]` is all anchors with a `class` as a ***[descendant](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector)***.

Basically, any element descending from an `<a>`, which starts with or contains the class `icon-` will be targeted.

What you want is to select all anchors starting with or containing that class **themselves** - `a[class]`:

```
a[class^="icon-"], a[class*=" icon-"] {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #1BA1E2;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjkQT/9/)

Comment: I'm a complete css noob.  Thanks!  Is the 2nd selector actually required?  Not exactly sure what it does since i coped this code from font-awesome in an attempt to override something.

Comment: @user1133619: The first selector is the more appropriate one, and yes they both do the same thing in this context.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - but you first need to remove the space between the type selector and the attribute selector and the space in the attribute value:

```
a[class^="icon-"], a[class*="icon-"] {
text-decoration: none;
color: pink; /* get rid of the # */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8YdD/1/

Comment: And now the question has changed it to `#1BA1E2` which is decidedly *not* pink...?!